# Rendering A Partial In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble saving date from a partial  that I created in **_form.html.erb**. The file name of the partial is **_education.html.erb**. This is how it's currently stated in _form.html.erb as                             `<%= render partial:'clients/education' %>` I cant figure out what I'm missing. I'm thinking it might be setting the partial as a local variable but I'm not sure.When I remove the partial the form works just fine.

**_education.html.erb**

```
    <%=form_for(@client, html: {class: "pure-form pure-form-stacked", multipart:true}) do |f| %>
<!-- START CUSTOM TABS -->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <!-- Custom Tabs -->
              <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-left">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1-1" data-toggle="tab">School</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#tab_2-2" data-toggle="tab">Employment</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#tab_3-2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1-1">
                   <b><%= f.label :ed_id, "School" %></b>
                                    <%= f.collection_select :ed_id, Ed.all, :id, :school, {prompt: "Choose School"}, class: "btn btn-info", class: "pure-input-4-24" %>
                  </div><!-- /.tab-pane -->
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2-2">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1-">
                    <b><%= f.label :employment_id, "Employment" %></b>
                                    <%= f.collection_select :employment_id, Employment.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose Status"}, class: "btn btn-info", class: "pure-input-4-24" %>
                   </div>
                   </div>
                  </div><!-- /.tab-pane -->
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_3-2">
                  ...
                  </div><!-- /.tab-pane -->
                </div><!-- /.tab-content -->
              </div><!-- nav-tabs-custom -->
            </div><!-- /.col -->

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <!-- Custom Tabs (Pulled to the right) -->

            </div><!-- /.col -->
            <% end %>
          </div> <!-- /.row -->
          <!-- END CUSTOM TABS -->
```

**Here is the controller for the client form**. I made sure that I added the ed_id to the params because it has a belongs_to in client.rb and has_many in ed.rb

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_client, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /clients
  # GET /clients.json
  def index
    @clients = Client.all.uniq.order("created_at DESC")
    @clients_count = Client.uniq.count
  end

  # GET /clients/1
  # GET /clients/1.json
  def show
  @notes = Note.where(client_id: @client.id) #Where a note belong to the current account
  end

  # GET /clients/new
  def new
    @client = Client.new
  end

  # GET /clients/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /clients
  # POST /clients.json
  def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.save
        format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @client }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /clients/1
  # PATCH/PUT /clients/1.json
  def update
    #if params[:remove_image]
    #@client.remove_image!
    @client.save
  #end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.update(client_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @client }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  # DELETE /clients/1
  # DELETE /clients/1.json
  def destroy
    @client.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to clients_url, notice: 'Client was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_client
      @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def client_params
      params.require(:client).permit(:firstName, :lastName, :dob, :gender_id, :remove_image, :insurance_id, :state_id, :ed_id, :rsource_id, :image, :race_id, :employment_id, :comments, :email, :phone, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode)
    end
end
```

**Here is an short version of the form.**

```
<%=form_for(@client, html: {class: "pure-form pure-form-stacked", multipart:true}) do |f| %>
     <% if @client.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@client.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this client from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @client.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
            <!-- beginning of rails code -->
            <form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
                <fieldset>
                    <!-- <legend>Client Information</legend> -->
                    <div>
                    <h2 class="account">Client Information</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pure-g">
                        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
                            <%= image_tag @client.image_url, class: "image-client" if @client.image? %>
                            <%= f.label :image, "Client Image" %>
                            <%= f.file_field :image %>
                            <%= f.check_box :remove_image, id: "my-checkbox", :data => { :size=>'mini', 'on-color'=>'success', 'on-text'=>'Done', 'off-text'=>'Yes' } %> Remove Image?
                        </div>

                        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3 firstname">
                            <%= f.label:firstName, "First Name" %>
                            <%= f.text_field :firstName, class:"pure-u-2-5", type:"text", placeholder: "First Name",  required: true %>

                             <%= f.label :lastName, "Last Name" %>
                             <%= f.text_field :lastName, class:"pure-u-2-5", type:"text", placeholder: "Last Name" %>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Employment Information -->
                    <h2 class="employment">Employment Status</h2>
                    <div class="pure-g">
                        <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
                           <%= render partial:'clients/education' %>
                        </div>
                        <!-- End of Employment Information -->
                        </div>
                    <!-- Client Note -->
                    ...
                    <!-- End of Client Note -->
                </fieldset>
                <div class="actions">
                <%=f .submit class: "btn btn-primary" %> <%= link_to 'Cancel', clients_path, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
            </div>
         <% end %>
         </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the locals to the _education partial:

```
<%= render partial:'clients/education', locals: {f: f} %>
```

And then in your _education partial, you don't need another `form_for` declaration; just keep going with your `<%= f.collection_select...`, etc.

Hope this helps! :-)